# Is xbox game bar resources widget open-source?

Tags: windows-10, xbox

I was aiming to modify the resources widget of xbox game bar to see if I could include GPU temperature as well in it, and was wondering if the source code of that widget was open-source. Since the GPU temperature is available in the task manager, could someone also help me with some resources regarding how I would communicate with the task manager for that purpose. Does the task manager has some API of some sort?

Comment: Only thing I could find is this: https://github.com/microsoft/XboxGameBarSamples